# MIPS program in array

Tags: arrays, assembly, load, mips, store

I am trying to solve this problem but when I run it I got error don't know what's wrong? Here is the question:

array2: .word   300, 70, 1400, 5, 127

Put array2 elements in DESCENDING order using only addi, load, and store instructions

HINT:

- Use a series of load words to load each array element into a separate register
- Use a series of store words to put the previously loaded values back into each of the array element memory locations

NOTE: No loops or conditional branches are needed

```
addi $t0,$0,300
addi $t1,$0,70
addi $t2,$0,1400
addi $t3,$0,5
addi $t4,$0,127

lw $s0, 0x0($t0)           # get array2[0]; $s0 = 300
lw $s1, 0x4($t1)           # get array2[1]; $s1 = 70
lw $s2, 0x8($t2)           # get array2[2]; $s2 = 1400
lw $s3, 0xc($t3)           # get array2[3]; $s3 = 5
lw $s4, 0x10($t4)          # get array2[4]; $s4 = 127
sw $s3, 0x0($t0)           # array2[0] = 5
sw $s1, 0x4($t1)           # array2[1] = 70
sw $s4, 0x8($t2)           # array2[2] = 127
sw $s0, 0xC($t3)           # array2[3] = 300
sw $s2, 0x10($t4)          # array2[4] = 1400
```

Comment: _"I got error"_. _What_ error? You should include the _full, exact_ error message in your question.

Comment: That's not descending order, but ascending. And the code does not what your comments say.  After first `addi` `t0 = 300`, then the first `lw` does load value from memory at address `300` ... probably nowhere near `array2` address. It's also not clear how you should load address `array2` into register without the pseudo-op `la` (it's sort of impossible unless you treat it as fixed constant, then the series of `addi` may be enough to re-create such value), or you may maybe use pseudo-op `lw $t0, label($t1)`? But that will emit also other native instructions. Feels almost like blind leads blind..

Comment: i.e. I'm not sure what the `addi` even should be used for, if you can just load+store the data on the desired positions. And because the code does not react on the data, you don't need even to load the old values, just store the new values (i.e. create final array), that's real-world solution in such case (when code doesn't have to sort real data).